# Cross-compiler path

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I have some compilers for different architectures:

```
$ > whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz

$ > whereis arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc /usr/share/man/man1/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.1.gz

$ > whereis arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: ~/.local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

gcc is for my workstation. It was installed in system path.

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc is for ARM target without hard float. It was installed in system path too.

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc is for ARM target with hard float. It was installed in my `$(HOME)/.local/` directory.
And I have added this directory to binary path in the `.bashrc` script:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

The system command `whereis` works true for all this compilers and shows valid path to binary executable file.

I wanted to compile some project for ARM with help `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` compiler, but I have received this:

```
as: unrecognised option '-mcpu=cortex-a53'
```

Error during assembler. Seems that my build system wish to use assembler for my x86, not `arm-linux-gnueabihf-as`.

After the installing `arm-linux-gnueabihf` to `~/.local` into the one some directories are appeared:

```
 ~/.local> ls -l
arm-linux-gnueabihf/
bin/
gcc-linaro-5.3.1-2016.05-linux-manifest.txt
include/
lib/
libexec/
share/
```

If i will go to `bin/` I will see the binbary files:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-addr2line*  arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp*        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar*      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb*       arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm*       arm-linux-gnueabihf-size*     isort*
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar*         arm-linux-gnueabihf-elfedit*    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm*      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran*  arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy*  arm-linux-gnueabihf-strings*  pylint*
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as*         arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++*        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib*  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gprof*     arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump*  arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip*    pyreverse*
arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++*        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc*        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov*        arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld*        arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib*   epylint*                      runtest*
arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++filt*    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5.3.1*  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-tool*   arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd*    arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf*  gdbserver*                    symilar*
```

This path was added to `$PATH`.

But if i will go to `./arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin` and will do `ls`, i will receive empty directory. 
I can overcome the error, if i will add some symbolic links to this directory:

```
ar -> ../../bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar*
as -> ../../bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-as*
gcc -> ../../bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc*
ranlib -> ../../bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib*
strip -> ../../bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip*
...
```

After this my assembler error disappears and I can successfully compile project for ARM-target. But after this I can't compile anything for my workstation x86.

Could anyone explain me what i should to do to successful compiling and for ARM and for x86, please?

**UPD**:
I have the Makefile for ARM:

```
CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-gnueabihf-
CC            = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
AS            = $(CROSS_COMPILE)as

INCLUDES      = -I./
SRC           = main.c
TARGET        = my-arm-target

all: $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -o $(TARGET)
```

And the same file for x86, but without `CROSS_COMPILE` variable:

```
CC            = gcc
AS            = as

INCLUDES      = -I./
SRC           = main.c
TARGET        = my-x86-target

all: $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: you need to have a `Makefile` for that, use that file as a script for cross-compilation (you would need to add cross-compiler path inside, and all options needed also); with this method, you can use your x86 compiler without any change

Comment: @damadam I have updated my post with adding Makefiles.

Comment: If I wll add the link `gcc -> ../../bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc*`  and others I will compile only for ARM. And not for x86

Comment: after creating a `Makefile`, you have to use the `make` command to do the cross-compilation (there is probably more to do before and after, i didn't remember) - i will confirm that by watching my previous report this evening

Comment: Yes, I use `make`  command to build this.

`~ cd arm-proj; `
`~ make; `
`**success**!`
And then: 

`~ cd ../x86-proj`
`~ make`
`**as error**!`

Comment: you must use `make` **only** for cross-compilation, if you want to compile for computer (a client access for your embedded system for example), just use the usual way like `gcc main.c` (or another compiler)

Comment: @damadam, Yes, it is will work true. It seems it is strange decision, because if I have for PC a large project with nested different makefiles, I shoild use `make` and not just `gcc`

Comment: @damadam, for example, I have just tried to build the Linux kernel for arm with help  `make`. 
Linux building system uses compiler for x86 for some scripts and arm-compiler for my target simultaneously.
That's why your decision will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a script for each architecture you want and use it to switch environments so you are using that architecture's tools.  makefiles for a specific architecture may assume gcc is the appropriate compiler, so your script should ensure that.  example:

```
MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3
C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed
LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
#######
CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc
CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip
export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH
export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
```

source the above script (. script) before your run your makefile, then the appropriate tools should be used.  Note, some of the items are commented out in the above example since I didn't need them.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work.
If I will compile the Linux kernel for ARM I will get errors, because it needs simultaneously and gcc-x86(my workstation) and gcc-arm(my target).

Comment: Please pay attention to the links which I remove for normal gcc-x86 work (see question). May be I have problems there.

Comment: I removed links and reinstalled arm-compiler. It's true way :)